# Speed of Manipulate with Plot3D & ParametricPlot3D

Tags: performance-tuning, manipulate

I am trying to generate a 3d animation showing two ripples interfering at a point which can be chosen. In my 3d modelling, I want to show the cross-section of the ripple towards that point. I wrote the code that correctly display all the elements but when I ran the animation, it was choppy and sometimes, after a beep from my com, the animation stop updating and nothing works thereafter.

The functions s1, s2, p1, p2 and r are all Initialization Code.

Here is my code:

```
    ω := 0.125 π;
s1[x0_, λ_, x_, y_, a_, t_] := 
  x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[(x^2 + (y - a)^2)] - ω t];
s2[x0_, λ_, x_, y_, a_, t_, phase_] := 
  x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[(x^2 + (y + a)^2)] - ω t - 
     phase];
p1[x0_, λ_, p_, a_, t_] := 
  x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[36 + Abs[(p - a)]^2] - ω t];
p2[x0_, λ_, p_, a_, t_, phase_] := 
  x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[36 + Abs[(p + a)]^2] - ω t - 
     phase];
r[x0_, λ_, p_, a_, t_, phase_] := 
  x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[36 + Abs[(p - a)]^2] - ω t] +
    x0 Cos[(
       2 π)/λ Sqrt[36 + Abs[(p + a)]^2] - ω t - 
      phase];
Manipulate[
 Show[
  Plot3D[s1[x0, λ, x, y, a, t], {x, 0, 6}, {y, -2.5, 2.5},
   AxesLabel -> {"distance \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "slits \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", "\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"z\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)"},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.2},
   ImageSize -> {400, 400},
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 25,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-1, 1}},
   PlotStyle -> {LightOrange, Opacity[v1]},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (-p + a) x + 6 y > chop a],
   SphericalRegion -> True,
   ViewPoint -> {5, -4, 5}],(* Ripple from source 1 *)
  Plot3D[s2[x0, λ, x, y, a, t, phase], {x, 0, 6}, {y, -2.5, 
    2.5},
   Mesh -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 25, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-1, 1}},
   PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[v2]},
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (p + a) x - 6 y > chop a]],(* 
  Ripple from source 2 *)
  ParametricPlot3D[{u, (p - a)/6 u + a, 
    x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[
         u^2 + ((p - a)/6 u)^2] - ω t]}, {u, 0, 6}, 
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.006], Opacity[v4]}],(* 
  Wave from source 1 to point *)
  ParametricPlot3D[{u, ((p + a)/6) u - a, 
    x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[
         u^2 + ((p + a)/6 u)^2] - ω t - phase]}, {u, 0, 6},
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006], 
     Opacity[v5]}]], (* Wave from source 2 to point *)
  Grid[{
   {"Time, \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"t\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 
    Control[{{t, 0., ""}, 0., 15., 1., Appearance -> "Open"}], 
    "Opacity of Ripple 1", Control[{{v1, 0.25, ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]},
   {"Position of P", 
    Control[{{p, 1., ""}, -2.5, 2.5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Open"}], 
    "Opacity of Ripple 2", Control[{{v2, 0.25, ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]},
   {"Slit Position, \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"a\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", 
    Control[{{a, 1., ""}, 0.5, 2., 0.5}], "Opacity of Resultant", 
    Control[{{v4, 1., ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]},
   {"Amplitude, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[
StyleBox[\"x\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"], \(0\)]\)", 
    Control[{{x0, 0.3, ""}, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}], "Opacity of Wave 1", 
    Control[{{v5, 1, ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]},
   {"Wavelength, λ", 
    Control[{{λ, 0.5, ""}, 0.2, 2., 0.1}], 
    "Cross-Section View", 
    Control[{{chop, 6., ""}, {-40. -> "Full", 6. -> "Cross-Section"}, 
      ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]},
   {"Phase of \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(2\)]\) rel. to \
\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(S\), \(1\)]\), \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(ϕ\), \
\(i\)]\)", Control[{{phase, 0., ""}, 0., 2 π, 0.25 π}], ""}},
  Dividers -> {{{False, False, True, False}}, False}, 
  Spacings -> {{0, 2, 10, 2}, 0}, Alignment -> Left],
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Comment: Hi Wongy,
what's your question exactly? A general trick is to use less plot points when the sliders are active: `PlotPoints -> ControlActive[15, 50]`.

Comment: For me it is smooth and I cannot reproduce the beep and the consequent shutdown of the kernel.

Comment: I also can not reproduce the problem. Animation runs smoothly and controls are responsive during animation. I ran the code on V11.3 under MacOS 10.13.4/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no one seem to be able to reproduce the problem the OP is experiencing

Comment: Wongy, how much ram are you working with? Same goes for @m_goldberg I find that precompiling/precomputing is key here. Take your desired output and export tables of all of values you want to manipulate through, then import and step through the precomputed values that way!! Works like a charm and usually doesn’t blow up your ram :)

Comment: @C.E. How much ram do you have? Thies that trick is awesome, I will use that most definitely!!!

Comment: @CATrevillian. I have 8 GB ot ram.

Comment: Hi all, apologies for not stating my question clearly. My issue is that my com is running the animation very slowly e.g. 2 fps..and occasionally com makes a beep and things come to a halt and animation does not update anymore.

Comment: My com is 6700HQ with 16GB ram. I checked and my processor is running at 60+%. No other programmes are taking up much processing cycle (mostly <2-3%).

Comment: Oh..I m running mathematica 12.0 on windows 10 pro

Comment: @Wongy I’ll post an answer tomorrow hopefully, as a guide to help you w this, I have a similar system (v12 and w10)

Comment: @Trevillian much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, but a suggestion for improving your code by using `Row` to display plot and control labels. I think `Row` makes the label formatting easier to write and certainly easier to read when displayed on this site,

```
Manipulate[
  Show[
    Plot3D[s1[x0, λ, x, y, a, t], {x, 0, 6}, {y, -2.5, 2.5},
      Mesh -> None,
      PlotPoints -> 25,
      PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2.5, 2.5}, {-1, 1}},
      PlotStyle -> {LightOrange, Opacity[v1]},
      RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (-p + a) x + 6 y > chop a],
      SphericalRegion -> True,
      ViewPoint -> {5, -4, 5}],
    Plot3D[s2[x0, λ, x, y, a, t, phase], {x, 0, 6}, {y, -2.5, 2.5},
      Mesh -> None,
      PlotPoints -> 25,
      PlotStyle -> {LightBlue, Opacity[v2]},
      RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, (p + a) x - 6 y > chop a]], 
    ParametricPlot3D[
      {u, (p - a)/6 u + a, x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[u^2 + ((p - a)/6 u)^2] - ω t]}, 
      {u, 0, 6},
      PlotPoints -> 50,
      PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.006], Opacity[v4]}],
    ParametricPlot3D[
      {u, ((p + a)/6) u - a, x0 Cos[(2 π)/λ Sqrt[u^2 + ((p + a)/6 u)^2] - ω t - phase]}, 
      {u, 0, 6},
      PlotPoints -> 50,
      PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thickness[0.006], Opacity[v5]}],
    BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.2},
    ImageSize -> {400, 400},
    AxesLabel ->
      {Row[{"distance ", Style["x", "TI"]}],
       Row[{"slits ", Style["y", "TI"]}],
       Style["z", "TI"]}],
  Grid[
    {{Row[{"Time ", Style["t", "TI"]}], 
      Control[{{t, 0., ""}, 0., 15., 1., Appearance -> "Open"}],
      "Opacity of Ripple 1", 
      Control[{{v1, 0.25, ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]}, 
     {"Position of P", 
      Control[{{p, 1., ""}, -2.5, 2.5, 0.05, Appearance -> "Open"}],
      "Opacity of Ripple 2", 
      Control[{{v2, 0.25, ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]},
     {Row[{"Slit Position, ", Style["a", "TI"]}], 
      Control[{{a, 1., ""}, 0.5, 2., 0.5}],
      "Opacity of Resultant", 
      Control[{{v4, 1., ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]},
     {Row[{"Amplitude, ", Subscript["x", Style["0", "TI"]]}], 
      Control[{{x0, 0.3, ""}, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1}], 
      "Opacity of Wave 1", 
      Control[{{v5, 1, ""}, 0., 1., 0.25}]}, 
     {"Wavelength, λ", 
      Control[{{λ, 0.5, ""}, 0.2, 2., 0.1}],
      "Cross-Section View", 
      Control[{{chop, 6., ""}, {-40. -> "Full", 6. -> "Cross-Section"},
        ControlType -> RadioButtonBar, 
        Appearance -> "Labeled"}]}, 
     {Row[{"Phase of ", Subscript["S", 1], " rel. to ", Subscript["S", 2], ", ", 
           Subscript["ϕ", Style["i", "TI"]]}],
      Control[{{phase, 0., ""}, 0., 2 π, 0.25 π}], ""}},
    Dividers -> {{{False, False, True, False}}, False},
    Spacings -> {{0, 2, 10, 2}, 0},
    Alignment -> Left],
  ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
  SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

Note: "TI" is built-in but not well documented shortcut that produces nice-looking italic symbols. It is a shortcut for Times Italic.

Comment: @goldberg, will certainly implement your suggestion. thanks a lot